# What does this multi mov instruction do?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I came across the following multi `mov` instruction:

```
mov eax, 1, 2, 3
```

What does this instruction do? Where can I find the correct documentation for this instruction?

Comment: Where did you see that? It's not a valid x86 instruction.

Comment: IDA disassembled it, and it was in a 64 bit (x64) binary.

Comment: Can you paste the fragment of disassembly with this line?

Comment: Your answer can be found [here](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf) between page 958 and 1007. Good luck on your quest...

Comment: @alexanderh, there is no such x64 instruction.  You are mistaken and your comment is a distraction.

Comment: @peterferrie, I'm not mistaken. I never stated the instruction or the use of more than two arguments for MOV exists. The answer can be found between those pages because it shows that MOV has a single source and a single destination. I read through those pages to verify the usage when I saw bread's question. Thought it would be helpful.

Comment: @alexanderh, it's not helpful to suggest that the answer can be "found" there.  The answer can be "found" by looking out the window, too, but by choosing that manual, you imply that the instruction exists.  It's more likely that the OP was mistaken about the output in some way, and thus has not returned to comment.

Comment: @peterferrie I'm guessing that alexanderh's intention was something along the lines discussed here: http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/. Namely an attempt to "reform a help vampire". And as such his comment is beneficial to the community as a whole.

Comment: I am closing this question as there has been no input from the OP and it most likely seems to the case that he was mistaken.

Comment: [GCC 7.3.0 C Error: too many memory references for `mov'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51290417/995714)